# How to track the execution flow (the functions being called)

Tags: go, concurrency, execution, goroutine

I worked on languages like PHP and Python but recently I got a Go project to maintain which utilizes several workers and goroutines.

In PHP or Python, we can know about the execution of code as its all synchronous calls. But I am finding it very difficult to understand how the code execution takes place in Go, especially in workers and goroutine. Can anyone suggest me any tools by using which I can get the execution flow(the name of the function being called)?

For example, if there is one API in which there are various goroutines and inside those goroutines, other goroutines are called, so how to know in which sequence these functions are called.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its "harsh" title. I have a strong feeling that we have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Go runtime trace tool will help you to trace , but you need to add trace option in go code start

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "runtime/trace"
)

func main() {
    trace.Start(os.Stderr) //start the trace 
    defer trace.Stop() // defer to the end
    .... //rest of the code
}
```

Then use ,

```
go run main.go 2> trace.out  
then use the trace tool
go tool trace trace.out.
```

This link has more info https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/go-execution-tracer/

Comment: Printing at stderr is not really ideal. What if there's another error or anything being printed in stderr. Would be better to just write it directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

> [I]f there is one API in which there are various goroutines and inside those goroutines, other goroutines are called, [...]

There isn‘t.

Comment: Maybe this bit of information calls for a bit more explanation... ;)